# How to make sure cronjobs get spread around a Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to run cronjobs on a K8s cluster that test the health of nodes. I need to ensure that it will continue to work if there's a network partition.

I've thought of 2 possibilities:

1. Run multiple replicas of the cronjob on each invocation, and use anti-affinity rules to make sure they're run on different nodes
2. Find a way of configuring K8s to distribute successive cronjobs on nodes in different zones.

I can't find any information on either. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you know that there are liveness and readiness probes that can constantly _probe_ each pod for health by executing a command or making a HTTP request?

Comment: This is for health of the nodes. I need to run node problem detector across the whole cluster

Comment: Well then a daemonset seems like a proper choice.

Comment: The descheduler runs as a cronjob (this is the cronjob, not node problem detector). I could maybe run it directly instead of as a cronjob, but that's why I'm asking this question, to see what's possible.

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve? https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Controlling which nodes cronjobs are run on. I need them to be sequentially run on nodes in different AZs, or simultaneously across multiple AZs. If that's not possible i'll take a different approach